# .htaccess, get the value after a period and then redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, period

I am trying to redirect a URL using a `.htaccess` file. The URL structure is like:

http://mydomain.com/folder/.anything_goes_here

Note the dot in the above Url. I want to remove it somehow using `.htaccess`.

I have tried using `RewriteRule` but it's not working.
Here is the code I used:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/folder/.(.*+)/?$ /folder/$1 [L]
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The period has a special meaning in regular expressions (it means "any character"). In order to explicitly specify a period, you need to escape it.

```
RewriteRule ^/folder/\.(.*+)/?$ /folder/$1 [L]
```

Comment: thank you for the reply but that doesn't solve my problem, also a point i forgot to mention was:
in the first place i want to remove this period because it gives me a 403 error. i will paste the whole .htaccess file from office for better understanding of the problem.

Comment: @ZainBaloch, can you clarify what you mean by "it's not working"? What behavior, exactly, are you expecting? What behavior, exactly, are you instead seeing?